# VGG16 takes much longer to train than expected

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

Using transfer-learning I am trying to train VGG16 in Keras using Google Colab.  Following is the code from the notebook: (note: the outputs are written as comments)

```py
    from keras import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
    from keras.applications import vgg16
    from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input as vgg_pi
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    from keras.models import Model

    base_model = vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                             input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    for layer in base_model.layers:
      layer.trainable = False
    base_model.summary()

    # Total params: 14,714,688
    # Trainable params: 0
    # Non-trainable params: 14,714,688

    x = base_model.output
    x = Flatten(name='flatten', input_shape=base_model.output_shape)(x) 
    x = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=x)
    model.summary()

    # Total params: 14,965,578
    # Trainable params: 250,890
    # Non-trainable params: 14,714,688

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])


    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        fill_mode='nearest',
    )
    validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
    )

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/domat/solo-dataset/train/', 
            target_size=(224, 224),
            batch_size=32,
            class_mode='categorical',
    )
    validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/domat/solo-dataset/validation/',
            target_size=(224, 224),
            batch_size=32,
            class_mode='categorical',
    )

    # Found 11614 images belonging to 10 classes.
    # Found 2884 images belonging to 10 classes.

    # check if GPU is running
    import tensorflow as tf
    device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
    if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
      raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
    print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))

    # Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0

    t_steps = 11614 // 32
    v_steps = 2884 // 32
    history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
                                  epochs=500, 
                                  steps_per_epoch=t_steps, 
                                  validation_data=validation_generator,
                                  validation_steps=v_steps,
                                 )

    # Epoch 1/500
    #   8/362 [..............................] - ETA: 41:02 - loss: 2.9058 - acc: 0.2383
```

So, for some reason, it takes around 40 minutes for a single epoch, and I don't really get why it's so slow.
Previously, I was playing around with different parameters (adding more fully connected layers) and the each epoch finished in around 3 minutes, although it was obviously overfitting, since there were 14mil parameters that were free, and the dataset is way smaller.

Anyone has any idea on how to approach this? I've tried like a million things and it simply is too slow. I couldn't even manage to get back to the original configuration to see what I was doing previously so that each epoch finishes in about 3 minutes.

Comment: Did you ensure that the environment is set to GPU?  Even if the GPU is present, you must manually set the runtime to GPU.

Comment: Yes, I did. What's even stranger is that after the first epoch lasts for an hour, the other last for a few minutes only
`Epoch 1/5
362/362 [==============================] - 6260s 17s/step - loss: 1.2611 - acc: 0.6735 - val_loss: 0.9555 - val_acc: 0.7712
Epoch 2/5
362/362 [==============================] - 159s 440ms/step - loss: 0.9351 - acc: 0.7800 - val_loss: 1.1295 - val_acc: 0.7903
Epoch 3/5
362/362 [==============================] - 156s 431ms/step - loss: 0.8751 - acc: 0.8033 - val_loss: 0.8300 - val_acc: 0.8219
`

Comment: Very weird indeed....

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility of slow hard disk read?

Answer (score -1):

using colab setting to set GPU mode for your environment.

Comment: OP has tried this.  He is experiencing strange behaviour.